# How to embed a triple double quote in a raw string

Tags: string, kotlin, escaping

Suppose we have a raw string as follows:

```
val myRawString = """line 1
line2
line3"""
```

Suppose the value we want to represent as a raw string has a line which itself contains a triple double quote. For instance, line4 should be `this line has """ (triple double quote)`
How can we accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot escape anything in a raw string, but you can use string templates, and you can escape inside those, so you could do this:

```
val myRawString = """line 1
line2
line3
this line has ${"\"\"\""} (triple double quote)
"""
```

Answer (score 2):

One way that I've seen mentioned in a similar question on the Kotlin slack was to declare a variable:

```kotlin
val qqq = "\"\"\""
val myRawString = """line 1
line2
line3
this line has $qqq (triple double quote)"""
```